# Bitwise operations in BC?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bc

```
$ bc
BC> ibase=2
BC> 110&101                     // wanna get 100
(standar_in) 8: syntax error
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language) informs that the ops are "|, & and ^". It may be that they work only in certain BC-types or I misread something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those operators are listed in the section ['Missing' operators relative to C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language#.27Missing.27_operators_relative_to_C), which ends with "... are not available in POSIX bc"

Answer (score 6):

Despite bc won't do it, you can use arithmetic expansion directly on the terminal if you use bash.

To XOR 44 and 61, you can do:

```
echo $((44^61))
```

If you want to use binary code, then:

```
echo $((2#110^2#101))
```

See [Numerical Constants](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/numerical-constants.html) for changing the base.

See [bitwise operators](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html) section to peep at available operators.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia article is pretty clear that these ops aren't in either POSIX bc or gnu bc.  The man page has no mention of them either.